# Blazor render dynamic Markup with Components inside

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to render some dynamic HTML with `Blazor` Components in them.
E.g.:

```
<div>
    Text
    <Component Attribute1="A1" />
</div>
```

Now, this HTML Snippet comes from a database and not from Code, so I am looking for some way to force Blazor to (re?-) render the content and resolve the Component into its `HTML-Expression`.

I already tried something with `RenderFragment`, but that did not work.
I also read about using the `RenderTreeBuilder`, but that is so very low-level, I would need to make it so granular, that it would be easier to use a `RegularExpression` and replace the component in the incoming HTML with some predefined placeholder-laden-HTML.

Does anyone know an easier way? Or some way to force Blazor to reevaluate the incoming `HTML/Razor/Blazor-String`?

Comment: if your code from database is pure html, you can use (MarkupString) cast. and if its component, you have to use some switch to create components or using BuilderRenderTree.

Comment: I already used MarkupString, but I want the markup-code from db to contain component names, I specifically created for the editors of said markup-code, to make their life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know an easier way? Or some way to force Blazor to re-evaluate the incoming HTML/Razor/Blazor-String?

Straight answer is not possible. You can't store markup code and somehow feed it into the Renderer at runtime.

Why?

Markup code, such as:

```cs
<div>
    Text
    <Component Attribute1="A1" />
</div>
```

is compiled by the Razor compiler into a standard C# class that produces code like this:

```cs
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        //...
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddMarkupContent(1, "Text");
        builder.OpenComponent<Counter>(2);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "Attribute1", "A1");
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();
        //...
    }
```

It's part of the compilation process, not a runtime option.

Comment: That is what I read... so I need to replace everything per RegEx or some other mechanism myself. Thanks for the straight answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from "MrC aka Shaun Curtis" is correct, and I will leave it marked as answer, I just want to share my solution for it.

Since I luckily only have to support a modern web browser (no IE anymore!) I am free to delve into HTML5 with all it's bells and whistles.

So I am using [HTML5 Web Components](https://kinsta.com/blog/web-components/) in combination with `MarkupString`s.

My input string looks like this

```html
<my-custom-html-a-tag url="some url">the <b>DISPLAY TEXT</b></my-custom-html-a-tag>
```

and gets decomposed into something like this

```html
<div class="someClass">
  <a href="some url" onclick="() => something predefined">
    the <b>DISPLAY TEXT</b>
  </a>
</div>
```